# Run R script from java

Tags: java, r, rjava, rscript, rserve

I've got a problem when I try to run a R script from Java . I truly look for an answer of this problem on internet but nothing works.

I've used Rserve and Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Rscript myScript.R") but neither of them works with my program.

please help me

**this is java code**

```
RConnection c = new RConnection();
                double d[] = c.eval("rnorm(10)").asDoubles();
                org.rosuda.REngine.REXP x0 = c.eval("R.version.string");
                System.out.println(x0.asString());
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Rscript TestR.R");
```

Here is the error message that is being thrown when I add Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Rscript "+rScriptFileName); to the code above:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
>           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
>           at algo.Testtest.main(Testtest.java:23)
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
>           at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
>           ... 5 more

Comment: You may need an absolute path to the executable. The file not found exception implies the executable was not found. IIRC, `exec(...)` will not search your path.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to use the Renjin interpreter [Download Renjin](http://www.renjin.org/downloads.html)

```
private static final ThreadLocal<ScriptEngine> ENGINE = new ThreadLocal<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScriptEngine engine = getScriptEngine();
    try {
        System.out.println("myScript");
        engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("src/myScript.R"));
        engine.eval("Square(19)");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | NullPointerException | ScriptException e) {
        System.out.println("An exception occured: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static ScriptEngine getScriptEngine() {
    ScriptEngine engine = ENGINE.get();
    if (engine == null) {
        // Create a new ScriptEngine for this thread if one does not exist.
        RenjinScriptEngineFactory factory = new RenjinScriptEngineFactory();
        engine = factory.getScriptEngine();
        ENGINE.set(engine);
    }
    return engine;
}
```